# 128 bit key issue in AES algorithm Java/ Java Script

Tags: java, javascript, encryption

I need to encrypt values in my Java code with user choice key and decrypt the values in Java script module.

Below is my Java code to encrypt the values. Here I am generating 128 bit key value from the user choice key and same is using to encrypt the values.

```
String plainText = "Hello, World! This is a Java/Javascript AES test.";
        try {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey("12345".getBytes());
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");

            AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(
                    Base64.decodeBase64("5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w=="));

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher
                    .doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception in crypto...");
        }

public static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        String s = new String(raw);
        System.out.println("raw key.." + raw);
        return raw;
    }
```

Above code printing the below values:

```
raw key..[B@45b9ce4b
vN2GouJcVli/rFMDHEwCNZejraO5cQxBtlo5D64qkaRTkxxRTIo+Vm38H4fUZp7ABxj7ul0Ha6bO5aFxMzMY0g==
```

When I use the above values to decrypt in JS code , I am not getting any response.

```
<html>
<head> 

<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script >
var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('vN2GouJcVli/rFMDHEwCNZejraO5cQxBtlo5D64qkaRTkxxRTIo+Vm38H4fUZp7ABxj7ul0Ha6bO5aFxMzMY0g==');
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('[B@45b9ce4b');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w==');
document.write(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    { ciphertext: encrypted },
    key, 
    { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: iv,  })));
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>hsd h </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Please point me If there's anything missing from my code or please suggest me if any alternative to produce the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is incorrect in your JS code. In your Java code you called `System.out.println()` using a `byte[]` as an argument which will not give you meaningful output. `[B@45b9ce4b` is not valid Base64 data.

To fix this you need take the `byte[]` representing the key and Base64 encode it into a String and then print the string.

A comment on key generation:

You should avoid using a random number generator to derive key material from user input (i.e. a password). The correct way to create key material from user input is by using a key stretching algorithm.

You should absolutely use a standard algorithm for this such as [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). In Java you can get a key factory for this via `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")`;