# Java to JS and JS to Java encryption using cryptojs

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, aes, cryptojs

I got on this post a couple of weeks ago and worked perfectly:
[Compatible AES algorithm for Java and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321049/compatible-aes-algorithm-for-java-and-javascript)

Now, I need to do the reverse operation, but once in java, I am getting this exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
```

This is my "reverse" operation I did in JavaScript:

```
var rkEncryptionKey = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('u/Gu5posvwDsXUnV5Zaq4g==');
var rkEncryptionIv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w==');

function encryptString(stringToEncrypt) {
    var utf8Stringified = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(stringToEncrypt);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(utf8Stringified.toString(), rkEncryptionKey, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: rkEncryptionIv});
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted.toString()).toString();
}
```

I though this would be all?

**[EDIT]**

Encrypted string is the following: `{"company_name":"asdfasdfasd","customer_name":"asdfasdfasdfasdf","phone_number":"asdfasdfasdfasdf","email":"asdfasdfasdfasdfads"}`

When doing the encrypt / decrypt from java to java it works, when doing so from java to javascript, also works, but from javascript to java, not working.

**Java Code**

```
public String toJson(final String encrypted) {
    try {
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64("u/Gu5posvwDsXUnV5Zaq4g=="), "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.decodeBase64("5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w=="));
        byte[] decodeBase64 = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(decodeBase64), "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This should not happen in production.", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here is an example that worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321049/compatible-aes-algorithm-for-java-and-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted.toString()).toString();
```

to

```
return encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

The `encrypted` object usually stringifies into an OpenSSL format which might also contain the salt. If you're only interested in the actual ciphertext, then you need to stringify the `ciphertext` property.

Note that `toString()` takes an optional encoding function. Use the one that you need.

Comment: I no longer get the exception, but once converted, the string does not match the js encrypted one, which is a JSON string. The result is a bunch of numbers / letters

Comment: I don't see where a JSON string might come from. Doesn't the absence of an exception tell you that the decryption worked?

Comment: the function encryptString is called after a JSON.stringify(obj), so I know the source to be encrypted is JSON, I am expecting the reverse operation to give me back a JSON string, but it's not the case.

Comment: Completely sorry, this is the right thing, I compared the wrong conversion strings.