# How to decrypt a String in java

Tags: java, angularjs, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to decrypt a string which is encrypted in front end(angualrjs) while calling a rest service in java using angular js. I am able to encrypt the string using `$crypto.encrypt` ( using CryptoJS).I am passing encrypted value as argument using `$http.get` method.

But I am not familiar on how to decrypt the value in java.

encryption key in my config:

```
app.config(['$cryptoProvider', function($cryptoProvider){
       $cryptoProvider.setCryptographyKey('ABCD123');
}]);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess this depends on the cryptoalgorithm you used.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382014/java-to-js-and-js-to-java-encryption-using-cryptojs

Comment: What's the point of encrypting it on the client side? You *are* using HTTPS anyway, right?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you're using CryptoJS, there is already an answer posted.

[How to decrypt an encrypted AES-256 string from CryptoJS using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151211/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-aes-256-string-from-cryptojs-using-java/29152379#29152379)

However, if you're using SSL/TLS, this encryption is not very effective. Because, even as the password is sent encrypted, there is need to store the password in clear text on the server-side for this purpose - which is not advisable. It is better to securely hash your passwords for authentication.